# Android Studio Alt+Enter auto import settings

Tags: android-studio, import, autocomplete, android-studio-import

I have a class in my Android Studio project called Ranking. I want to use this class in a different package in the same project, so I have to import the class. Normally I would type in "Ranking" and when it turns red, put my pointer on it and press Alt+Enter. This would bring up this menu:

[image]

After hitting Enter it would ask which class to import:

[image]

At some point I accidentally hit some keys while doing this for the Ranking class. I saw a window open and immediately disappear. This presumably changed a setting somewhere.

Now, whenever I use Alt+Enter this class is imported immediately without asking which one to import:

android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService.Ranking

When I hover over the class name, it doesn't say "Multiple choices" anymore as it does for Date:

[image]

[image]

I cannot find the setting. Does anyone know where it is?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

on above setting select ask instead of All....

Answer (score 0):

I just found it!

The option is under *File -> Settings* and then *Editor -> General -> Auto Import*

Here you can define classes that should be ignored by the Alt+Enter auto-import.